# Signed library for GAC use prevents IsAssignableFrom check from working as it used to

Tags: c#

I have a library that handles plugins for my application, I just recently started signing it for GAC use and now my plugin loader prevents plugins that were not built with the exact same library from being loaded due to the following check when dynamically loading plugin dll's

```
typeof(IMPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(pluginType)
```

`IMPlugin` being the interface for my plugin system contained in the library in GAC, `pluginType` being the reflected type found in the plugin dll.

I understand that signing the library now presents a public key where it used to be null and the mis-match results in the types being considered inequal.

Is there a replacement comparer that I can use that does not take the public key into account? I already have an internal check that checks a value in each plugins meta to make sure the library meets the plugins minimum requirements so i'm not worried about version mis-matching.

Comment: It could only go wrong like you describe if you forgot to rebuild the host as well.  Required.  If this is a breaking change, pretty likely since that also invalidates other plugins that use that interface, then you can't use the GAC.  Which, frankly, plugins should never use.

Comment: Well I make many changes over time to the interface, most of which are backwards compatible to plugins, and the system I have in place where I check minimum required version prior to loading the plugin works fine. But now am expanding the application to multiple applications, different UIs and a service, so moving to the GAC was an inevitable outcome as my library is not merely a plugin loader, but rather a framework used in various applications that happens to be plugin empowered.

Comment: Suppose there's a way. Suppose you have a function that returns `true` for your example. Then what? You still can't cast, so what good is it to you to get `true`?

Comment: It all worked just fine prior to signing.

Comment: After signing you only need recompile everything once. After that you can change the assembly at will again. This is because the signer identity is now part of the assembly identity.

Comment: Im leaving this question open incase somebody determines an intricate solution to this, but at present, the only way I can figure out how to keep my library version independent is to not sign it thus not use it in GAC. I will have to find another method to avoid multiple instances of my library across multiple applications.

Comment: Did you read my comment? The solution is to sign and recompile once. After that the assembly identity stays the same even if you change the signed assembly.

Comment: Unfortunately in practice that did not seem to work. The assembly still did not like any differences, almost like there is a hash check going on or something.

Comment: Also, the plugins are loading the assembly as a reference and not through Assembly.Load() so that may have something to do with it as the reference may be expecting a specific thumbprint if the assembly is signed?

Comment: I doubt there is a hash check. If that was true you could never patch the .NET Framework, or anything else. You must have made a mistake executing the procedure.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, but I think .net and other microsoft assemblies may implement a hidden `bindingRedirect` property. What I did was sign, compile then deploy my lib to GAC, then drop the reference to the lib in my app and plugins then re-add it (to ensure using the proper token from signing). It worked fine for the first execution, but as soon as I made a insignificant change in the library such as adding a comment, re compile then re-deploy to the GAC the plugins stopped working.

Comment: So... Using the GAC in combination with ngen seems to have resolved the issue.